# Extract data from nested JSON and convert to TSV

Tags: json, jq

I'm looking at parsing nested json.  For the example below, I know that it appears on Github - however due to sensitivity I cannot post my actual data on here.

I've Been looking at `jq` for formatting, and can pull each component out, but cannot merge them together such that it looks like the below.

BEcuase of software restrictions, I cannot use 3rd party code.

input:

> ```
> {   "asgs": [
> {
>   "name": "test1",
>   "instances": [
>     {"id": "i-9fb75dc", "az": "us-east-1a", "state": "InService"},
>     {"id": "i-95393ba", "az": "us-east-1a", "state": "Terminating:Wait"},
>     {"id": "i-241fd0b", "az": "us-east-1b", "state": "InService"}
>   ]
> },
> {
>   "name": "test2",
>   "instances": [
>     {"id": "i-4bbab16", "az": "us-east-1a", "state": "InService"},
>     {"id": "i-417c312", "az": "us-east-1b", "state": "InService"}
>   ]
> }   ] }
> ```

output:

```
test1   i-9fb75dc       us-east-1a      InService
test1   i-95393ba       us-east-1a      Terminating:Wait
test1   i-241fd0b       us-east-1b      InService
test2   i-4bbab16       us-east-1a      InService
test2   i-417c312       us-east-1b      InService
```

EDIT:
Current code is such that I loop through all the instances of `instances` using and then append the names.  For example:

```
cat sampleData.json | jq -c '.' | while read i; do
echo $i, & jq '.instances' sampleData.json
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I have updated my thought process and added some code in here.  I'm extremely new to bash and this sort of work - any help that I can have is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. https://old.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/fye4qm/help_extract_data_from_nested_json/

Comment: @vintnes that was me also posting on Reddit.   Thank you for spotting.

Answer (score 5):

A slight shorter (though marginally more complex) version of @anubhava's answer:

```
jq -r '.asgs[] | .name as $n | (.instances[] | [$n, .id, .az, .state] | @tsv)' file.json
```

This "remembers" each name before producing a tab-separated line for each instance, inserting the correct name in each row.

Comment: It doesn't have to be complex though. `.asgs[] | [.name] + (instances[] | [.id, .az, .state]) | @tsv` is shorter and clear enough.

Comment: @oguzismail you are missing a dot. `.asgs[] | [.name] + (.instances[] | [.id, .az, .state]) | @tsv` works nicely. I'm surprised you haven't made it an answer; it's better than the other answers imho.

Comment: @Bean it's just a slightly improved version of chepner's answer

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `jq`:

```
jq -r '.asgs[] | .name + "\t" + (.instances[] | .id + "\t" + .az + "\t" + .state)' file.json
```

```
test1   i-9fb75dc   us-east-1a  InService
test1   i-95393ba   us-east-1a  Terminating:Wait
test1   i-241fd0b   us-east-1b  InService
test2   i-4bbab16   us-east-1a  InService
test2   i-417c312   us-east-1b  InService
```

Comment: FANTASTIC Answer - let me know where I should be sending the beers to!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic `map` to create an extra entry per-instance:

```
jq -r '.asgs[] | [.name] + (.instances[] | map(.)) | @tsv'
```

Comment: @peak Key sorting is irrelevant to this question and my solution handles duplicate instances correctly.

Comment: This solution assumes that the keys of the "instances" are all given in the desired order and that all of the "instances" have exactly the same set of keys. It would be safest to specify the desired keys and their order in the query.  The fact that the example does not highlight the issue only makes it more important for the caveat to be highlighted.